# “I hope he visit us more often” Why is this wrong?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

> I desire he visit us more often.

This is correct, right?

> I hope he visit us more often.

Why is this incorrect? Why should I use “visits” instead?

Comment: I visit. We visit. You visit. You all visit. He visit**s**. They visit.

Comment: Note that in some dialects, you'll hardly hear the 'll when someone says "I hope he'll visit us more often".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to look into **[subjunctive mood](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm)**.

The verb "desire" falls into the subjunctive category, so the following verb takes the subjunctive form:

> I desire that he visit me more often.

Notice the additional "that", which is required.

"Hope" does not fall into the subjunctive category, so it does not need the subjunctive mood:

> I hope he visits tomorrow.

There isn't a lot of general rule around this. It's axiomatic. Typically, sentences that express an achievable want/expectation will use subjunctive mood. "Hope" and "wish" are well-known exceptions.

Keep in mind that subjunctive mood is not widely used colloquially, but it is important in formal/professional use.

Comment: Beat me to it! I was doing some research and came up empty-handed for "hope".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I can't remember ever reading a good explanation. I speculate that *hope* and *wish* are more about hypothetical thoughts than actions for someone. "I recommend he see a doctor" is a request for an action. "I hope he will see a doctor" is my own personal thought. We have come to use it as a suggestion in disguise but, literally-speaking, *hope* and *wish* are still personal thoughts, as opposed to directives. That's my guess.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. “I desire that he visit me more often.” “I desire he visit me more often.” “I desire that he visits me more often.” “I desire he visits me more often.” Someone please tell me which are acceptable.

Comment: @Yamacure Only the first one of those four is acceptable.

Comment: Dang... this is completely correct, yet it's reminded me how frustrating it is that there's no real "rule" here beyond "because it is" meh

Answer (score 8):

> I *desire* he visit us more often.
>   I *hope* he visit us more often.

*If* the OP was attempting to construct two subjunctive sentences, the grammar was almost there.

> The English subjunctive is a special, relatively rare verb form that expresses something desired or imagined.
>
> We use the subjunctive mainly when talking about events that are not certain to happen. For example, we use the subjunctive when talking about events that somebody:
>
> **wants** to happen
>   **anticipates** will happen
>   **imagines** happening
>
> [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm)

Although the subjunctive has long gone out of fashion in colloquial British English, it still has its supporters across the Atlantic, where you are most likely to encounter it. See for example how it is used in an article by the American newspaper *[The Hill](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/411998-trump-says-he-hasnt-visited-troops-overseas-because-hes-very-busy)*

> *“Trump told The Associated Press that while he doesn’t think it is “overly necessary” **that he visit** a military base in a combat zone, **he plans** to do so “at some point” in the future.”*

The subjunctive mood is more common in ***formal writing and speech***, and this continues to be also true in British English.

Many American English speakers would consider the [mandative subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive) *“visit”* to be fully correct, if any of the following verbs was followed by a *that* clause.

*to advise (that), to ask (that), to command (that), to demand (that), to desire (that), to insist (that), to propose (that), to recommend (that), to request (that), to suggest (that), to urge (that)* etc.

> I ***desire*** ***that*** he visit us more often
>   I ***suggest*** *that* he visit us more often
>   I ***prefer*** *that* he visit us more often

**Unfortunately, the verb *hope* is NOT included in that list.**

I tried, briefly, searching online for a possible explanation, but I could not find any.

When any verb follows *hope*, in the present simple tense, the third person  singular *always* requires an -s or -es marker.

> I/we hope she **visits** us more often
>   I/we hope he **stays** longer next time
>   He hopes she **passes** her exam

A special mention for *wish* which is also used in the subjunctive mood but primarily with past tense forms

> 1. If I **were** a rich man (obligatory [Youtube](https://youtu.be/RBHZFYpQ6nc?t=32) link)
> 2. John **wishes** he **were** taller
> 3. We **wish** we **could** afford to move home

Comment: A good answer +1 but I would question the statement 'The subjunctive mood is more common in formal writing and speech, and this continues to be also true in British English.' Except in set phrases ('God save the Queen') the subjunctive mood is very rarely used in modern British English in any kind of speech. And if it is used in formal writing then that is very formal writing.